# C# - Array Copying using CopyTo( )-Help

Tags: c#

I have to copy the following int array in to Array :

```
int[] intArray=new int[] {10,34,67,11};
```

i tried as

```
Array copyArray=Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int),intArray.Length,intArray);
intArray.CopyTo(copyArray,0);
```

But ,it seems i have made a mistake,so i did not get the result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 10, 34, 67, 11 };
Array copyArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), intArray.Length);
intArray.CopyTo(copyArray, 0);
foreach (var i in copyArray)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

You had one extra "intArray" in your Array.CreateInstance line.

That being said, this can be simplified if you don't need the Array.CreateInstance method (not sure if that's what you're trying to work out, though):

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 10, 34, 67, 11 };
int[] copyArray = new int[intArray.Length];
intArray.CopyTo(copyArray, 0);
```

Even simpler:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 10, 34, 67, 11 };
int[] copyArray = (int[])intArray.Clone();
```

Comment: Yes that extra array is the cause of  the problem

Answer (score 9):

Are you aware that an `int[]` is already an `Array`? If you just need to pass it to something accepting `Array`, and you don't mind if it changes the contents, just pass in the original reference.

Another alternative is to clone it:

```
int[] clone = (int[]) intArray.Clone();
```

If you *really* need to use `Array.CopyTo` then use the other answers - but otherwise, this route will be simpler :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
int[] copyArray = new int[intArray.Length];
Array.Copy(intArray, copyArray, intArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, just use

```
int[] copyArray = (int[]) intArray.Clone();
```